# How to prevent labels to overlap

Tags: gnuplot

I am running the following command to draw a few X,Y points in gnuplot:

plot "Output.tsv" using ($2+3):($3+3):1 with labels, "Output.tsv" using 2:3

Some of the data points are very close to each other and it makes the label unreadable. Is there a way to ask gnuplot to eliminate/reduce the overlap between labels?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could consider 3 options:

1) make your graph huge and hope your labels do not overlap
2) plot the points as different series with each item having its own legend
3) use letters instead of labels, you can put a letter at each point using

```
plot "???" using 1:2
plot "" using 1:2:(stringcolumn(3) ne 'compare to' ? 'if equal' : 'if not equal' ) with labels
```

the stringcolumn function looks in column 3, compares the value to the string 'compareto' and if there is a match it puts 'if equal' at that location, otherwise 'if not equal'

Hence, I see something like Simulator in your graph, you could keep the green point and put an S with it/on it using

```
plot "" using 1:2:(stringcolumn(3) ne 'Simulator' ? 'S' : '' ) with labels
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: +1 I like the stringcolumn function and didn't know about that one.